# Route docker container internet traffic through openvpn container

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, iptables

I want to route the traffik from and to the internet from my docker containers through a VPN container:

```
Internet <---> VPN Container <---> Containers  A,B,C
```

I tried connecting containers A,B,C to an internal network to restrict access to the internet. THe VPN container is connected to the internal net aswell as the default net but due to the strict separation of docker networks I am not able to `traceroute` from A,B,C to the internet.

What would be a way to achieve this?